# API call to retrieve all public information of Facebook user?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql

I know I can call each individual field via something like
`/---ID----?fields=gender,languages,age_range,bio,birthday,education,email,hometown`

Is there a quicker way than listing every single field?

It is ok if the user has most of these fields locked down with their privacy settings, I just want it to pull what is available.

Answer (score 0):

just try:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/{{ username or uid }}?access_token={{access token goes here}}

Example:
https://graph.facebook.com/zuck?access_token=###
```

will give all the public information available for that user.

Comment: I'm afraid that only gives me id, first_name, last_name, link, gender, locale and updated_time, even when I set everything (education, workplace etc) to Public

Comment: did you add the access token?

Comment: When I copy&paste the access token from the Graph Explorer it works fine but I can't get it to work using the token produced in my SDK script.

Comment: are you including those all the required permissions when retrieving the access_token from your SDK script

Comment: I am using `$url = $facebook->getLoginUrl(array(
        'req_perms' => 'email,user_birthday,status_update,publish_stream,user_photos,user_videos,friend_email,friends_about_me,user_about_me'`
 I don't know what the difference is in the token request between the Graph Explorer and my own.